# Is there a reason why the index isn't written as a tree?

Tags: git

When you delve a bit into the internals of git (but haven't got as far as reading the codebase :) ), you come to understand that, when you run `git add file.txt` or `git add dir/file.txt`, an object is created for the *file* (a blob is written in git storage), but no objects are created for the *directories* (e.g: there is no tree object storing the content of the index, hierarchical levels included).

You can create that tree by calling `git write-tree`, but this is a separate action.

My question is:

Is there an ulterior motive behind that behavior ?

Are there some specific reasons why running `git add` doesn't also create tree objects straight ahead ?

---

On top of sheer curiosity, I'm also wondering what it would take to have a reflog for the index. If you had a tree, you could store a commit and a floating ref pointing to that tree, much like the stash does.

Comment: I also understand the (good) reasons why git is very conservative about its commands behavior, perhaps there could be some flag to `git add` or some configuration setting to add this behavior ?

Comment: It _might_ have to deal with the fact that you could have _conflicts_? If you created trees in the index, they would have to keep conflict state support in a structure that is thought of to be part of a commit _without_ conflicts. That is what I have always _assumed_ to be the reason why.

Comment: I think one of the possible reasons could be to reduce redundant objects as much as possible. A file could be edited and added multiple times before being committed.  Along with the creation of a new blob, one or more tree objects, depending on the depth of the file, would be created at the same time. If we edit several files but add them one by one, how many tree objects would be just left over at last?

Comment: I would ask little differently. Why would you want to create blob for folder? I mean, is there any reason to create snapshot of what folder contains, except the fact that it would be harder to have something in folder we don't want to have in repository? (or at least I assume it would be that way) And of course, we already have information of folder anyway in current approach, no need for redundancy as @ElpieKay mentioned.